# How to get user data by providing user name or user profile field

Tags: 7, services

I am using postman. I want to provide the username or a user profile field say roll no and fetch the user's information. What should be the URL.

I am able to fetch the user information when I provide the `uid` using the following URL :

```
http://[yourdomain]/[endpoint]/user/[uid]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the user data by providing username, you can use pass `name` (username) as a parameter to the service URL like follows

```
http://example.com/<endpoint path>/user?parameters[name]=krishna
```

If you want to pass either username or other user profile fields you can achieve that using [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) module. After installing this module make sure to enable it under service resources list.

Create a **view** with contextual filter(s)

**Executing view via views resource**

After enabling "views" resource in your services endpoint you can do GET request to:

```
http://example.com/<endpoint path>/views/<view name>
```

This will execute a view and pass results.

**Possible arguments:**
- display_id: views display

- args: array of view arguments
- filters: array of view filter values
- offset: views offset
- limit: limit views number of results
- format_output: boolean whether we would like to get themed view or data

Comment: http://example.com/<endpoint path>/user?parameters[name]=krishna this works !

Comment: i made a view and added User:Name in contextual filters.So what should be the url now.

Comment: tried few urls. they are not working. please help.

Comment: @TulikaSharma URL would looks like follows-
`http://example.com/<endpoint path>/views/<view name>/[filter]`
make sure that you've created services view.

Comment: it gives error 404 not find : Could not find the controller

Comment: but args[0]=8728 works where 8728 is the field value

Comment: Ok will try that

Answer (score 0):

Please get the user token with below URL:

http://[yourdomain]/[endpoint]/user/token (you might need to login first)

Use the token as x-csrf-token with headers with your URL with GET method:

http://[yourdomain]/[endpoint]/user/[uid]

if above is working then you can choose query parameter as below.

http://[yourdomain]/[endpoint]/user?name=kalpan

Comment: I think this doesn't provide an answer to the question. OP wants to get the user information by providing username or  user profile field.

Comment: Sure, i have updated my answer.

Comment: I think by providing `?name` doesn't gives the result. It returns all the users instead

Comment: yes it provides all the users. doesnt work.